An old fairy tale about magic place where all wishes were coming true
I am trying to identify the earliest reliable source or mentioning of the following fairy tale, which I remember not very well.
The story describes a magical place (probably with a tree in it) where every desire or thought immediately comes true. A man accidentally walks up to that place. He is hungry, so some food instantly appears by. His second wish (which I don't remember) is also granted. Finally, the person realizes that this place must be governed by some really powerful demons. He gets scared. So, a scary demon materializes and kills the person.
